# The angle between two vectors

Tags: vectors, inner-products, angle

I'm just a new person here and hope that I can ask my question properly. Here is my question:

Find the vector $\vec{b}$, when the angle between two vectors is $30^\circ$ and one vector is given by $\vec{a} = \langle -1, 2, -3\rangle$ and the other one is given $\vec{b} = \langle x, y, z\rangle$. Unfortunately I couldn't find exact values for the element of vector $\vec{b}$. Could you guys give this problem a try and could you find exact numbers or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing the length of $b$ there is not a unique answer. If $b$ is a solution, then also any scalar multiple (like $2b$ or $3b$) is a solution.

Comment: If you know scalar products you may find mutiple such vectors $b$.

Comment: draw a picture and see how $\vec{b}$ should look like

Comment: @Nick Even knowing the length of $b$ does not determine it, since it still can end at any point of a circle in 3-space which is also in a cone with axis parallel to $a$ and apex angle 30 degrees.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, good point. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the dot product formula $a \cdot b=|a|\  |b| \cos(30)$ where $|a|$ and $|b|$ are the lengths of the two vectors (square root of sum of squares of components). The vector $b$ is not determined by your condition but is only restricted to lie in a cone making all 3-d locations of vectors $b$  with axis $a$ and apex of cone angle 30 degrees.